# In Python dictionary how to find a based on first value of the key?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, key-value-store

I am working with python dictionary to store the key value pair. I have duplicate keys such as for key 6 there are to values `[4,2], [5,1]`, which i can not store in the dictionary since it doesn't allow duplicate keys.

Therefore, I came up with indexing the key itself e.g. for key 7 there are 3 values so I stored them with index as:

```
{(7, 0): [6, 1], (7, 1): [5, 2], (7, 2): [4, 3]}
```

Based on above logic I generated the following dictionary:

```
{
(7, 0): [6, 1], 
(7, 1): [5, 2], 
(7, 2): [4, 3],

(6, 1): [4, 2], 
(6, 0): [5, 1], 

(5, 0): [4, 1], 
(5, 1): [3, 2], 

(3, 0): [2, 1], 

(4, 0): [3, 1]
}
```

My question is that how to find a set of values for a given key e.g. for key 7 I want to get the result as `[6,1], [5,2], [4,3]`.

**PS: Only python2.7 standard libraries should be used for the solution.**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: using (6,0) and (6,1) as keys just as a way of getting around not being able to use duplicates seems a bit odd to me. if you want [4,2], [5,1] from the key 6, why not just do 6 : [[4,2], [5,1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your answer:

```
print([v for k,v in d.items() if k[0]==7])
```

result:

```
[[6, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3]]
```

but you're not taking advantage of the dictionary. For your task I would suggest `collections.defaultdict` with `list` as default argument

Demo:

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(list)

d[7].append([6,1])
d[7].append([5,2])
d[7].append([4,3])

print(d[7])
```

result:

```
[[6, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3]]
```

Comment: I think your approach is much better. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your approach for creating a dict is not Good. Instead of doing this, you should create a dict which holds values of all your items as `list`.

Hence, your dictionary structure should be like:

```
my_dict = {
    7: [[6, 1], [5, 2], [4, 3]],
...
}
```

Then you can simply access all the values of `7` with:

```
my_dict[7]
```

Take a look at [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

---

If you still want to go with your approach, you may use *list comprehension* to fetch the values as:

```
key = 7

[v for k , v in my_dict.items() if k[0]==key]
#                                   ^  matches 0th index of key and returns
#                                      returns all the values as list
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually change the structure of your dictionary a bit to make it a dictionary that had numbers for keys (i.e., your 6 and 7 that you're talking about here) and then list of tuples for the values. Like this:

```
{7: [(6, 1), (5, 2), (4, 3)], 6: ... }
```

You could also have a list of lists if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried doing something like this. Might this solve your problem?

```
for key in dict:
    for val in key:
        if val == 7:
            print 'yes'
```